# converting existing 2d grid based game to 3d using JLWGL

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, 2d

I have been tasked with creating a 2d game (In JAVA) for Computer Science 2A. 
I've created the game and all works well, but how do i go about converting this 2D game to 3D, ie. The game will be played in a 2D plane(2D array) but will rendered in 3D.

More specifically - Using JLWGL.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? A vague request for advice likely won't get much response here. As far as the OpenGL API goes I believe lwjgl is pretty much the same so any OpenGL tutorial should be applicable to lwjgl, perhaps outside of window initialization, which you can find tutorials for on their website : http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page#Getting_started

Comment: Tim: thanks for the link but i have been through it, i don't understand where to begin. But i shall push through!

Comment: What do you mean, to begin? If you followed the tutorials you should be able to have a really simple framework and load some simple quads and sprites. From there its a simple step to loading a cube, then a simple 3d model, then whatever you want. The only thing to do is just get started and practice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to automatize the creation of a 3D game (using textured 3D models) from a 2D-based game (made of sprites, or otherwise a set of animated 2D imagery).

---

As for making a 3D game that has 2D physics. Well, you will actually be creating exactly that, a 3D game that, in terms of physics, is one axis short or limited.

What that axis is depends on your game. "Z" **usually** (not a standard, you'll have to do your own tweaking!) refers to the **depth**, so in a PLATFORM game that moves just side-to-side (X axis) and up-and-down (Y axis), you would simply skip implementing any **player-commanded movement** for that Z axis.

Don't forget you **can't** simply skip everything related to the axis altogether! The characters and objects are 3D! So following the same example they would still have depth (Z-axis), and they'r animation will still make depth-related movements.

So, in the end, it is like [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1236185/tim) tried to explain, there is no "easy way" and you will just have to grasp how to do rendering of a 3D game (you just won't be using complex physics on it, but that's pretty much the only difference).